# awk to extract exact name in front of name

Tags: awk, sed

Friends,
Need to extract name from payload file. My payload file contains

```
"mobileAppTunnel": "disabled","name": "t1",
```

I need to extract only the name which is t1. Currently its t1 but it can be anything which I don't know, it can be 10 letter word or letter followed by number. 
Please help

Comment: I see you only accepted 1 of the answers to your previous 6 questions. Maybe take a look at [ask] so you can learn how to post better questions and so attract better answers?

Comment: Thanks Ed for the pointer will do that

Comment: Is it a JSON input ? I really think so

Comment: sorry @ravindrasingh I tested only one answer and posted there

Comment: @GillesQuenot yes its JSON input

Comment: Check my answer, **you need a JSON parser**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -F'[, | ]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){gsub(/"|:/,"",$i);if($i=="name"){gsub(/"|:/,"",$(i+1));print $(i+1)}}}' Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** a short version of `awk` here with different approach from 1st Solution.

```
awk -v RS="[ |,]" -v FS="" '/^"name":$/{getline;gsub(/"/,"");print}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation for solution 2nd:***

```
awk -v RS="[ |,]" -v FS="" '   ##Mentioning that record separator as either space or comma, then setting field separator to NULL here for all the lines.
/^"name":$/{                   ##Searching for a line which starts from "name": if yes then do following:
  getline;                     ##Using awk out of the box utility getline to take cursor to next line now.
  gsub(/"/,"");                ##Using gsub global substitution to substitute " with NULL in current line all of its occurrences.
  print}                       ##Printing the current edited/non-edited line now.
' Input_file                   ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Comment: how can I do multiple extract ? currently it is doing for name, but I also want to extract for protocol for example below awk helps to extract name, to the same line how can I add protocol    ` awk -F'[, | ]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){gsub(/"|:/,"",$i);if($i=="name"){gsub(/"|:/,"",$(i+1));print $(i+1)}}}' Input_file `

Answer (score 1):

Should be a fairly simple regex:

**In**:

```
"mobileAppTunnel": "disabled"
"name": "t1"
```

**Regex**:

```
/^\s*"name"\s*"(.+)"$/
```

**Out:**

```
t1
```

Comment: Good that you have given regex, but how user going to run it? It is better to give complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

### The proper way, using a real [json](/questions/tagged/json) parser :

```
$ cat file.json
{ "mobileAppTunnel": "disabled","name": "t1" }
$ jq -r .name file.json
t1
```

Check https://stedolan.github.io/jq/